# How to print this pattern

Tags: python-3.x

want to print the following pattern given below
number of row should be input by the user program needs to be compatible with any number of rows 
for example if user enters 5 rows

```
12345
2   4
3   3
4   2
54321
```

i tried using nested for loop

```
row=5
col=5
n=1
z=5
for x in range(1,row+1):
    for y in range(1,col+1):
         if (x == 1):
             print(n,end="")
             n=n+1
         else:
             print(end="")
    print("")
    for y in range(1,col+1):
        if (x == 1):
             print(z,end="")
             z=z-1
        else:
             print(end="")
    print("")
```

i expect this

```
12345
2   4
3   3
4   2
54321
```

the output i get is this

```
12345
54321
```

Comment: Perhaps add some additional prints to see where it diverges?

Comment: plz check the question again i edited it

Answer (score 1):

If loops are what you need, then this will do:

```
row = int(input('enter number of rows: '))

spaces = 0

for i in range(1, row + 1):
  print(i, end='')
  spaces += len(str(i))

print()

for i in range(2, row):
  print(i, ' ' * (spaces - 4), row - i + 1)

for i in range(row, 0, -1):
  print(i, end='')

print()
```

Output for `row = 5`:

```
12345
2   4
3   3
4   2
54321
```

Output for `row = 8`:

```
12345678
2      7
3      6
4      5
5      4
6      3
7      2
87654321
```

Output for `row = 10`:

```
12345678910
2         9
3         8
4         7
5         6
6         5
7         4
8         3
9         2
10987654321
```

Comment: number of row should be input  by the user program needs to be compatible with any number of rows

Comment: @KamranShehzad I edited the code to be dynamic, even though you didn't mention it in the question.

Comment: sorry my bad i should have mention it.thanks for helping out

Comment: @KamranShehzad You're welcome, you can accept this as answer if it helped.

Comment: one more question is there  any online platform where i can learn these pattern programs giving me headaches –

Comment: @KamranShehzad Not sure about patterns exactly, but you can try [codecademy](https://www.codecademy.com/learn/learn-python), it's great in general, a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

With out actually writing out the code, you could work with two circular arrays. `1,2,3,4,5` and `1,2,3,4,5`. One rotating left and one right. For the first and last iterations you print the whole array, and the inverse. For the middle ones, only print the first and last element.

```
`1,2,3,4,5` now rotate both `2,3,4,5,1` and `5,1,2,3,4`
`2,x,x,x,4` print [-1],[0], rotate again `3,4,5,1,2` and `4,5,1,2,3`
`3,x,x,x,3` print [-1],[0], rotate again `4,5,1,2,3` and `3,4,5,1,2`
`3,x,x,x,3` print [-1],[0], rotate again `5,1,2,3,4` and `2,3,4,5,1`
`4,x,x,x,2` print [-1],[0]
`5,4,3,2,1` print whole inverse
```

Comment: sorry got beginner level knowledge don't understands this code is beyond my level

Comment: @KamranShehzad, no problem, @MrGeek has a solid answer. Just use `row = input("Number of rows? ")` for user input

Comment: yea,any online platform where i can learn these pattern programs giving me headaches